# How to get local insights of Facebook page using graph API?

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api

I want to get following **local insights** of Facebook page using graph API

1. People Nearby:Hourly
2. Weekly
3. Overall
4. Check-ins

Please see the screen shot.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ki1D.png)

Comment: You can use the 'Graph API explorer' to see what all you can access and use in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get page insights by using this code and ask for page permissions ('manage_pages','pages_manage_cta') , and get page id first from your likes or managed pages and replace you page id in code with YOUR_PAGE_ID.
use FB php sdk version: facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev.

```
  $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => APP_ID,
  'app_secret' => APP_SECRET,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4', // or use v2.5 latest version
  ]);

  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

  $permissions = ['manage_pages','pages_manage_cta']; 

  $redirectUrl = 'http://localhost/fbapp.php';
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectUrl, $permissions);

  echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

After generating login url implement the code for response handling and getting required data.

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
  setcookie('accessToken',$accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

// Get user groups detail
$requestPageInsights = $fb->request('GET', '/YOUR_PAGE_ID/insights');

//Make a batch request
$batch = ['page-insights' => $requestPageInsights];

try {
  $responses = $fb->sendBatchRequest($batch);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
for a better view can use this:

foreach ($responses as $key => $response) {
  if ($response->isError()) {
    $e = $response->getThrownException();
    echo '<p>Error! Facebook SDK Said: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n\n";
    echo '<p>Graph Said: ' . "\n\n";
    var_dump($e->getResponse());
  } else {
    echo "<p>(" . $key . ") HTTP status code: " . $response->getHttpStatusCode() . "<br />\n";
    echo "Response: " . $response->getBody() . "</p>\n\n";
    echo "<hr />\n\n";
  }
}
```

And for getting other details visit on and use your related params/scope https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights